# C# process.start, how do I know if the process ended?

Tags: c#, process

In C#, I can start a process with

> process.start(program.exe);

How do I tell if the program is still running, or if it closed?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

[MSDN System.Diagnostics.Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx)

If you want to know *right now*, you can check the `HasExited` property.

```
var isRunning = !process.HasExited;
```

If it's a quick process, just wait for it.

```
process.WaitForExit();
```

If you're starting one up in the background, subscribe to the Exited event after setting EnableRaisingEvents to true.

```
process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
process.Exited += (sender, e) => {  /* do whatever */ };
```

Comment: This approch doesnt work for ASP.NET, not real asynch run. My web application is blocked while process is running.  Any Idea?

Answer (score 18):

```
Process p = new Process();
p.Exited += new EventHandler(p_Exited);
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"path to file";
p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
p.Start();

void p_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Process exited");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Be sure you save the `Process` object if you use the static `Process.Start()` call (or create an instance with `new`), and then either check the `HasExited` property, or subscribe to the `Exited` event, depending on your needs.

Comment: You can use the Process.Start(string) method since it returns an instance of Process. You can use that instance's Exited event.

Comment: @MikeMayer Good point; I always forget it works like that. Will edit.

Answer (score 1):

Assign an event handler to the [Exited](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited.aspx) event.

There is sample code in that MSDN link - I won't repeat it here.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [MSDN documentation for the Process class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx).

In particular there is an event  ([Exited](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited.aspx)) you can listen to.