# WPF form controls(Next button, cancel button) gets disabled in background

Tags: c#, wpf

I've a WPF page that contains next and cancel navigation to subsequent pages. Next button gets enabled based on certain validations. On click of another button in the page, another .exe gets opened and the 1st page goes to background. After finishing the tasks in opened exe, if the 1st page is not clicked, Next button and close button stay disabled. Once I click on the form, they get enabled.

I checked that if the 1st form is in background, CanExecuteChanged function gets called only when the form is clicked manually.

How to make the 1st form active again after the 2nd exe is closed?

Comment: Are you confusing page with process? Are you sure you are executing a new process (executable) rather than showing a new `Window`? Can you post your relevant code please?

Comment: Are you asking when [process is finished](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12273825/1997232) ?

Comment: I'm executing a new setup executable(a new process) from the first exe which consists of pages. On click of a button, the 2nd process is invoked.